# javascript json array output

Tags: javascript, json

Having a JSON string (shortened):

```
{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}
```

I would like to be able to call a function that returns the "long" value based on the "short" value:

like:

```
var test= 'Say '+get_value("_YES");
```

How can I do this?

Tried :

```
function f_lang(short_string) {
    var obj = json_string;
    var arr = [];
    json = JSON.stringify(eval('(' + obj + ')')); //convert to json string
    arr = $.parseJSON(json); //convert to javascript array

    return arr['line_array'][short_string];
}
```

with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object that contains the short value. Note that `Array#find` is not supported by IE. So if you need IE support and/or you're making lots of conversion like this, you should go with the dictionary approach.

```js
var str = '{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}';

var terms = JSON.parse(str);

function get_value(short) {
   var term = terms.line_array.find(function(o) {
     return o.short === short;
   });
  
  //in case the term isn't found, we'll prevent term.long from throwing an error
  return term && term.long;
}

var result = get_value('_YES');

console.log(result);
```

**Using a dictionary object**

Creating a dictionary with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and using it:

```js
var str = '{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}';

var terms = JSON.parse(str);

var termsDictionary = terms.line_array.reduce(function(d, t) {
  d[t.short] = t.long;
  return d;
}, Object.create(null));

function get_value(short) {
  return termsDictionary[short]; // you can use this expression without the function of course
}

var result = get_value('_YES');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Gives TypeError: termsDictionary is undefined on the dictionary example

Comment: Using it.
* var terms = str;

var termsDictionary = terms.line_array.reduce(function(d, t) {
  d[t.short] = t.long;
  return d;
}, Object.create(null));

function get_value(short) {
  return termsDictionary[short]; // you can use this expression without the function of course
}

console.log(get_value("_YES"));
*

Comment: gives TypeError: terms.line_array is undefined[Learn More]

Comment: var terms = JSON.parse(str) - it's a json that you need to parse. I'll update the examples.

Comment: Changed var terms = str;
to
var terms = JSON.parse(str);
and now it works.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a proper parsed JSON, you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), an ES6 feature.

```js
function getValue(short_string) {
    return (object.line_array.find(a => a.short === short_string) || {}).long;
}

var json_string = '{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}',
    object = JSON.parse(json_string),
    test= 'Say '+getValue("_YES");

console.log(test);
```

ES5 with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
function getValue(short_string) {
    var value;
    object.line_array.some(function (a) { 
        if (a.short === short_string) {
            value = a.long;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return value;
}

var json_string = '{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}',
    object = JSON.parse(json_string),
    test= 'Say '+getValue("_YES");

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```js
function f_lang(short_string) {
    var obj = {"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]};
    for (var i = 0; i < obj['line_array'].length; i++) {
      if (obj['line_array'][i]['short'] == short_string) {
        return obj['line_array'][i]['long'];
      };
    }
}

console.log('Say ' + f_lang("_YES"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var haystack = {"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}

console.log(haystack.line_array.filter(e => e.short === '_YES').long)
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
<script>
var str = '{"line_array":[{"short":"[common]","long":"undefined"},{"short":"_YES","long":"Yes"},{"short":"_NO","long":"No"},{"short":"_NOT","long":"Not "},{"short":"_SEARCH","long":"Search"},{"short":"_GO","long":"Go"}]}';

var terms = JSON.parse(str);

function get_value(short) {
   return terms.line_array.filter(function(o) {
        return o.short == short
   });

  //in case the term isn't found, we'll prevent term.long from throwing an error
}

var result = get_value('_YES');

console.log(result);
</script>
```