# How to find the value of an element in an object based on a selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in my state which looks like this:

```js
{
  city1: {
    name: 'Beijing',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HK0MBLLVO8',
  },
  city2: {
    name: 'Shanghai',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8wxzMiPo0U',
  },
  city3: {
    name: 'Chengdu',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlTVHr4-usg',
  },
};
```

I now need to access the value of the video element based on a selector (the name of the city).

How am I able to read the value of this specific video element?

So I have an other const that is called activeCity. Then based on this const I need to retrieve the value of the matching video element in the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript json array output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959718/javascript-json-array-output)

Comment: @OriDrori, the idea is (almost) exactly the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate through your object until you find the city with the name you need.

I wrote a function `getCityVideo(cityName)` that does this with a `for..in` loop.

```js
var cities = {
  city1: {
    name: 'Beijing',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HK0MBLLVO8',
  },
  city2: {
    name: 'Shanghai',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8wxzMiPo0U',
  },
  city3: {
    name: 'Chengdu',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlTVHr4-usg',
  },
};

function getCityVideo(cityName) {
  for (var city in cities) {
    if (cities[city].name === cityName) {
      return cities[city].video;
    }
  }
}

// example usage
document.write(getCityVideo('Shanghai'));
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Yet I have one problem now, when I now change the state of activeCity, the video doesn't change. But I don't understand why not.

Comment: I guess because this function only gets triggered when the page loads originally. So I would have to make sure it gets triggered every time I click to load a new activeCity.

Comment: @Deelux You're correct, you'd need to call the function every time you update the city.

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the original data into the format `{city: video}` like this.

```
var cities = {
  city1: {
    name: 'Beijing',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HK0MBLLVO8',
  },
  city2: {
    name: 'Shanghai',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8wxzMiPo0U',
  },
  city3: {
    name: 'Chengdu',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlTVHr4-usg',
  },
};
var transformed = {};
for (var key in cities) {
    transformed[cities[key]['name']] = cities[key]['video'];
}
```

And then access a city's video like this.

```
var video = transformed['Beijing'];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this questions. I think both answers are great but I can only accept one as a valid answer.

Comment: @Deelux Note that if you only need to find a city once the other answers works fine. But if you're doing more than one lookup you would get much better performance by only doing the transformation once.

And please feel free to upvote the answers you find useful.

Comment: Ok great to know. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the nesting object to array using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then iterate the array with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and get the video url:

```js
const getVideoFromCity = (cities, activeCity) => 
  // get the values of the cities, and iterate using find
  (Object.values(cities).find(
    // if the name equals the activeCity return true
    ({ name }) => name === activeCity 
    // get the video from the object found, or from the empty object - undefined - if no object was found
  ) || {}).video; 

const cities = {
  city1: {
    name: 'Beijing',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HK0MBLLVO8',
  },
  city2: {
    name: 'Shanghai',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8wxzMiPo0U',
  },
  city3: {
    name: 'Chengdu',
    video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlTVHr4-usg',
  },
};

const activeCity = 'Shanghai';

const result = getVideoFromCity(cities, activeCity);

console.log(result);
```